# Automatically close NERDtree when opening file

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have installed NERDtree 4.1.0.

I have mapped `<leader>n` to `:NERDTreeToggle<CR>`.

I would like to use this in a way where I can press `<leader>n`, then locate the deisred file in the explorer, press enter and have the NERDtree explorer disappear again, automatically.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Solved by putting `let g:NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 1` in my `.vimrc`.